# C# SignalR: HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I've been everywhere trying to find an answer to this so hopefully someone can help.

A little bit of background: I'm getting my feet wet with SignalR and attempting to expand on the [Chat Room Example](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr/). My idea is basically to have a list of users who have entered the room. I am attempting to do this by storing a list of usernames in a "users" cache key and maintaining and distributing this list when users login/logout. I want to access this list from within my hub's code when requested by the client.

When I use `Application` I get the desired results but it is my understanding that `HttpContext.Current.Application` is not the best way to go as it is only there for compatibility with classic asp. I see a lot of recommendations for `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance`, however, whenever I access this I get a `NullPointerException` on `ApplicationInstance`. What is the best way to manipulate some cache keys (or an equivalent) for what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using Application for this at all. If you simply want to cache and keep it up to date based on events such as login/logout, use a static member on your Hub class or object cache (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997357.aspx)

Comment: the static member idea was so simple and SO effective. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use a database, cache or a static variable to store your state. Avoid using HttpContext.Current inside of SignalR.